# JQuery delay() function being skipped

Tags: jquery, delay, wait

I'm having trouble getting some javascript and Jquery to delay the appropriate amount of time. I want to change some text, wait 5 seconds, then pop an alert.

Here's the code:

```
$('#result').html("Record has passed").delay(5000);
alert("Record has passed");
```

For some reason, the alert is running before jquery changes the #result and waits. Any solutions or anybody else see this problem?

I've tried

```
setTimeout($('#result').html("Record has passed"), 5000);
```

as well but still no luck.

Comment: I should also add that I've tried moving the .delay(5000) as well:
    $('#result').delay(5000).html("Record has passed");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.delay` method only works on animations and queued functions. Try using `setTimeout` instead.

```
$("#result").html("Record has passed");
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Record has passed");
},5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#result').html("Record has passed");
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Record has passed");
},5000);​
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RdX34/2/).

Answer (score 1):

if u still wanna use jquery delay, u can do like this:

```
$('#result').html("Record has passed").delay(5000).queue(function() {
  alert("Record has passed");
});
```